# Why is my while loop being skipped?

Tags: java, while-loop

I think my program is skipping my while loop, but I'm honestly not sure exactly what is happening. The function is supposed to reduce fractions by finding the GCD and then dividing numerator and denominator by that number.

```
    class Rational {

private int numerator, denominator;

//Constructor
public Rational (int num, int den) {
    numerator = num;
    denominator = den;
}

//Method for multiplying fractions
public Rational times (Rational that) {
    Rational x = new Rational (this.numerator*that.numerator, this.denominator*that.denominator);
    x = x.reduce();
    return x;
}

//Method for displaying fractions as strings
public String toString() {
    return new String(numerator+"/"+denominator); 
}

//Method for adding fractions
public Rational plus(Rational that) {
    Rational x = new Rational ((this.numerator*that.denominator)+(that.numerator*this.denominator), 
            this.denominator*that.denominator);
    //x = x.reduce();
    return x;
}

//Method for subtracting fractions
public Rational minus(Rational that) {
    Rational x = new Rational ((this.numerator*that.denominator)-(that.numerator*this.denominator),
            this.denominator*that.denominator);
    //x = x.reduce();
    return x;
}

//Method for dividing fractions
public Rational divideBy(Rational that) {
    Rational x = new Rational (this.numerator*that.denominator, this.denominator*that.numerator);
    //x = x.reduce();
    return x; 
}

public Rational reduce() {
    int a = Math.abs(this.numerator);
    int b = Math.abs(this.denominator);
    int c = Math.min(a, b);
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(a%c);
    System.out.println(b%c);
    if (a==0) {
        return new Rational (0,1);
    }
    else {
        while (((a%c)!= 0) && ((b%c)!= 0)) {
            c = c-1;
            System.out.println(c);
        }
        System.out.println(c);
        return new Rational (this.numerator/c,this.denominator/c);
    }
}
}   

public class RationalTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rational x = new Rational (6,4); //The fraction 6/4
    Rational y = new Rational (5,2); //The fraction 5/2
    Rational z = x.times(y); //Their product
    Rational w = x.plus(y); //Their sum
    Rational v = x.minus(y); //Their difference
    Rational u = x.divideBy(y); //Their quotient
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, x.toString()+" * "+y.toString()+" = "+z.toString());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, x.toString()+" + "+y.toString()+" = "+w.toString());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, x.toString()+" - "+y.toString()+" = "+v.toString());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, x.toString()+" / "+y.toString()+" = "+u.toString());

}

}
```

I'm getting the absolute value of the numerator and denominator to ensure that if the fraction is negative I'll be keeping that at the end. If the numerator is 0, I was asked to return (0,1). The question is about the while loop... it seems that it's being skipped completely. Any suggestions?

Comment: Provide some sample inputs and desired outputs for testing

Comment: Please give sample values of `a`, `b` and `c`... note that comparing floating point numbers for equality is rarely a good idea. Do they *need* to be `double` rather than `int`? Note that if you'd provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, that would help...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Common_pitfalls

Comment: Sorry, here is the full program. It was originally int instead of double, I was just trying a lot of different things to get the desired result, I changed it back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because always its condition is false.

In the first lines you set `c` equal to either `a` or `b`. So there are two possibilities:

- If `c == a`, then `a%c` will be zero. So the while condition is false.
- If `c == b`, then `b%c` will be zero. So the while condition is false.

Comment: This is the reason. You say that c = min(a, b) so a%c==0 or b%c==0 ALWAYS!

Comment: Hahahah, thank you so much! This is one of those been beating my head against the wall for way too long moments. Man I feel dumb.